# Seperating Duplicate Values in Multi Info Cards On Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Been struggling with a problem and can't seem to get past it.

Trying to express the sample table below as Multi Info Cards.

| Year | Description | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Work Description One | 25 |
| 2019 | Work Description Two | 21 |
| 2021 | Work Description One | 12 |
| 2019 | Work Description Three | 19 |

The cards need to display the description column based on the scores column. Currently row one and row three are combined due to having the same description, showing a sum value of 37.

The easiest way to differentiate would be based on the year but I am having trouble creating a measure/filter to achieve that.

Comment: You have a card and want to display the description there? And you want to use a slicer based on score column for filtering?

Comment: @Mik that's correct. The card has the description displayed but when it's the same description it combines the cards. It's already being filtered based on score, so I am looking for a way to split and show individual cards for each identical entry (who's only notable difference is the year.

Comment: It's not possible to have dynamic number of cards. You can show several values in a card for example: Score-Description; Year1;Year2... or use a table/matrix visual